# runtime error: index 2 out of bounds for type 'int [*]', leetcode Palindrome

Tags: arrays, c, runtime, palindrome

It's generating the error:

```
Line 18: Char 14: runtime error: index 2 out of bounds for type 'int [*]' [solution.c]
```

I tried to change line `int a[j]={0}, b[j]={0}, k=0;`
but the error is changing to:

```
solution.c: In function ‘isPalindrome’
Line 14: Char 9: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized [solution.c]
         int a[j]={0}; b[j]={0}, k=0;
         ^~~
```

and here is the code:

```
bool isPalindrome(int x){
    int j=0, i, k=x;
    if(x<0)
        return false;
    
    else {
        while(k>1)
        {
            k=k/10;
            j++;
        }
        int a[j], b[j], k=0;
        for(i=j; i>0; i--)
        {
            a[i]= x % 10;
            x=x-a[i];
        }
        b[j]=a[j];
        for(i=0; i<j; i++)
        {
            k=b[i];
            b[i]=b[j-i];
            b[j-i]=k;
        }
        for(i=0; i<j; i++)
            if(a[i]!=b[i])
                return false;
            return true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Once you've changed a multi-digit number into an array of digits, you _could_ simply compare the first with the last, then the 2nd with the 2nd last, etc. working your way toward the middle of the one array. That might be easier than dealing with two arrays...

Comment: @Fe2O3 thank you, but I still don't get why is there an error, is it related to my approach?

Comment: Let's say `j == 5`.When you declare an array like `int a[j];` the valid indices are 0 ... 4. This loop `for(i=j; i>0; i--)` starts at 5 but `a[5]` is out of range. You should start at `j - 1` and change the condition to `i >= 0`. `b[j]=a[j];` is also out of range and would only copy a single item, not the whole array which is what it looks like you are hoping for.

Comment: @Supernova_10 This code contains `x`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `a[]` and `b[]`, How do you _hope_ to keep track of what variable represents what aspect of the challenge. `k` dissolves to 0, `x` fades out of memory, `i` counts up... and down... and is somehow related to `j`... `k` reappears as a temp variable when elements of `b[]` (that contain nothing special) are swapped (to reverse the elements)... The code **obscures** the fact that `b[]` contains uninitialised values... Far, far too complicated. Too many moving parts... Simplify! Start there. The array boundary issue will become apparent.

Comment: Work it out by hand on paper, then adapt your algorithm to code. This is too complex. Use a code formatter--whitespace around variables and braces around blocks. Use expressive variable names.

Answer (score 0):

`int a[j], b[j], k=0;` this is not allowed cuz at compile-time, compiler needs to know the size of `a` and `b` (cuz they are both declared in stackframe), but at compile-time, `j` has not yet known. You have to specify the dedicated size for them e.g `int a[100] = {0}, b[100] = {0}`, note: size must larger than max `j`.